# Netbeans IDE - invalid jdkhome specified

Tags: java, windows, netbeans-8

**Netbeans 8.0.2** shows this error on startup [Netbeans 8.0.2 error on startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhXZ1.jpg). I searched for this error, but nothing works for me.

I modified the netbeans_jdkhome in `netbeans.conf` file, but  nothing. Then uncommented it, nothing. The error keeps showing up. It´s like there is another netbeans.conf file, but I don´t know where.
I´m running Windows 10 and have JDK 1.8 installed in **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101" .**

Answer (score 35):

go to `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc`, open the file `netbeans.conf` then change `netbeans_jdkhome` to the path of your JDK, `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"`

if you are not sure about the version of `jdk`, you can find it by typing in CMD `java -version`

Comment: As I have written in my question, I already tried modifying 'netbeans_jdkhome' variable in netbeans.conf. However, It still does not work.

Comment: @JiříMačák changing netbeans_jdkhome in netbeans.conf file solves problem. As you said there may exists another installation of netbeans in your computer.

Answer (score 6):

You may have a problem getting your edit to stick because you need Administrator Privilege to edit the netbeans.conf file.

Windows 10:

1. left mouse-click on the windows button on the task bar
2. type cmd.exe
3. windows search should list "Command Prompt - Desktop App"
4. right mouse-click on "Command Prompt - Desktop App"
5. select "run as administrator"
6. select the Yes button from User Account Control dialog box
7. from the command prompt change directory to where the netbeans.conf
   file is.
8. CD "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc"
9. type: notepad netbeans.conf
10. search for netbeans_jdkhome=
11. add the path to your jdk: netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program
     Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181"
12. save netbeans.conf
13. start Netbeans

Answer (score 2):

I found a decent solution for Windows users.

Go to your NetBeans install folder (for instance: `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc`), open the file `netbeans.conf` then just comment out the line:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"
```

to

```
#netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"
```

The '#' is for comment. You will see this in the file.

Then just run the NetBeans IDE as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set environment variable in cmd:

```
setx JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
```

I think you alredy have JAVA_HOME, but path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15.
You can check it in cmd. Just type it:

```
set JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I already have the JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101.

Comment: This has nothing to do with netbeans jdkhome. JAVA_HOME has different purpose. correct answer is posted by CY15

Answer (score 0):

To fix *Netbeans IDE - invalid jdkhome specified*
just find your `netbeans.config` and change the file path, like below:

`netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161"`

`netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10"`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just run netbeans64. You have to manually edit the CONF file in netbeans\etc folder. And set jdkhome variable. Then the installation goes smoothly.

Ignore all my previous comments. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First attempt at a powershell solution.

```
# fix path to jdk in netbeans.conf
# netbeans doesn't like unicode (utf-16)    

$conf = Get-Content 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 8.2\etc\netbeans.conf'

# string version of $jdk will have last dir found if there's more than one
$jdk = get-item 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk*'

# `" to embed "
set-content 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 8.2\etc\netbeans.conf' (
  $conf -replace 'netbeans_jdkhome=.*',"netbeans_jdkhome=`"$jdk`"")

if (-not $?) { exit 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant edit netbeans.conf for some reason, try re-installing netbeans

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier solution by just passing the parameter **--jdkhome** to netbeans executable (inside './bin' folder):

```
netbeans64.exe --jdkhome %JAVA_HOME%
```

You can create a **runNetbeans.bat** file at netbeans root directory with the following content:

```
%~dp0/bin/netbeans64.exe --jdkhome %JAVA_HOME%
```

PS: You can pass the directory of your JDK, replacing the JAVA_HOME environment.
PS2: Tested on Netbeans 12.