# How do I stop NetBeans from "popping up "invalid jdkhome specified" window

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

[image]

I previously had JDK 9 installed. Because of the issue NetBeans has with JDK 9, I deleted JDK 9 from my computer and installed JDK 8. 
Now, Netbeans doesn't have any issue anymore, except that it pops up this window whenever I open NetBeans. If I click yes on window, everything works fine. It just bothers me I have to click it every time I open NetBeans.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956102/netbeans-ide-invalid-jdkhome-specified

Comment: Attention Mac OS users: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52959955/2457251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the link in the OP comment points out, the cause of the problem is almost certainly an invalid value for **netbeans_jdkhome** in file **netbeans.conf**:

> **netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_161"**

Make sure that the string value references a valid JDK8 installation. (File **netbeans.conf** resides in the **etc** directory directory directly under the NetBeans installation directory.)

However, there are also a couple of other configuration settings worth checking:

- Select **Tools > Java Platforms** and verify that the **Platform Folder** is valid:

[image: JavaPlatform]

- Select **Tools > NetBeans Platforms** and verify that the **Platform Folder** is valid:

[image: platformManager]

As a related issue, although NetBeans 8.x does not support Java 9, you can download a beta version of Apache's NetBeans 9, which supports both Java 9 and Java 10, from the [Apache NetBeans site](https://netbeans.apache.org/). Note that:

- Installing NetBeans 9 has no impact on your NetBeans 8.x installation.
- You can safely run NetBeans 8.x and NetBeans 9 concurrently.

---

Update:

Try the following if you get an "*access denied*" error when updating **netbeans.conf** on Windows:

- Close NetBeans, then open **netbeans.conf** in Notepad.
- Make your changes and then save the file to any temporary location such as **C:\temp**.
- In Windows File Explorer move that file you just created to the NetBeans 8.x target directory (e.g. **C:\Program Files\NetBeans\etc**) to overwrite the existing version of **netbeans.conf**.
- Restart NetBeans.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to change the string that references "netbeans_jdkhome" to "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_161" but access was denied. How am I supposed to change the string value?

Comment: To  be clear, you should not specify the string value I provided. That was merely an example, and is unlikely to be correct on your machine. You want the value to be wherever you installed JDK8, which **might** be something like **"c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_161"**, but check before setting it. I updated my answer for your "access denied" problem.